# SigmaJS dragNodes: "Right hand side of instanceof is not an object"?

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

I'm playing around with node graphs using Sigmajs. 
Recently I tried to implement moving nodes in the graph but in the web-debugger I get an error saying *"TypeError: Right hand side of instanceof is not an object"* referring to the plugin `sigma.plugins.dragNodes.js`.

I followed the example given by the good folks at Sigmajs.org called *"drag-nodes.html"* and I believe I've included the packages correctly, yet I get the error.

The web-debugger refers to two places in the `sigma.plugins.dragNodes.js` file, these being: (At line 64)

```
if (renderer instanceof sigma.renderers.svg) {
    _mouse = renderer.container.firstChild;
}
```

and (at line 304)

```
if (!_instance[s.id]) {
  _instance[s.id] = new DragNodes(s, renderer);
}
```

This is my code:

```
<script src='{{ url_for("static", filename="js/sigma.min.js") }}'></script>
<script src='{{ url_for("static", filename="js/sigma.parsers.json.min.js") }}'></script>
<script src='{{ url_for("static", filename="js/sigma.plugins.dragNodes.js") }}'></script>


<div>
    <button onclick="AddNode()"> Click</button>
</div>
<div>
    <!-- testing function -->
    <button onclick="update()"> update</button>
</div>
<div> <!-- ONSUBMIT send: (fromNode, toNode) Not complete -->
    <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="value" id="value" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="AddEdge()" />
</div>
<div id="container">
<style>
 #graph-container {
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
 }
</style>

<div id="graph-container"></div>
</div>

<script>
var nodeCount = 0,
    edgeCount = 0,
    s,
    maxNodes = 20,
    maxEdges = 50,
    g = {
        nodes: [],
        edges: []
    }

s = new sigma({
    graph: g,
    container: 'graph-container',
    renderers:[ {
        container: document.getElementById('graph-container'),
        type: 'canvas'
    }],
    settings: {

    }
});

// Testing function only
function PrintNodes(){
    var edgeval = document.getElementById('value').value[0];
    alert(edgeval);
}

function AddNode() {
    s.graph.addNode({
        id: 'n' + nodeCount,
        label: 'Node ' + nodeCount,
        x: nodeCount,
        y: 5,
        size: 8,
        color: '#000000'
    });
    nodeCount =nodeCount +1;
    s.refresh();
}
function AddEdge() {
    var fromNode = document.getElementById('value').value[0];
    var toNode = document.getElementById('value').value[1];
    s.graph.addEdge({
        id: 'e' + edgeCount,
        source: 'n' + fromNode,
        target: 'n' + toNode,
        size: 8,
        color: '#FF0000'
    });
    edgeCount = edgeCount + 1;
    s.refresh();
}

// Testing function only
function update(){
    s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n){
        n.size = 34,
        n.color = '#000'
    });
    s.refresh();
}

// Initialize the dragNodes plugin:
var dragListener = sigma.plugins.dragNodes(s, s.renderers[0]);

dragListener.bind('startdrag', function(event) {
  console.log(event);
});
dragListener.bind('drag', function(event) {
  console.log(event);
});
dragListener.bind('drop', function(event) {
  console.log(event);
});
dragListener.bind('dragend', function(event) {
  console.log(event);
});


</script>
```

Why is this giving me that error? And any help to fix it is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You should show the place where `instanceof` is.

Comment: Added it to the post! Thanks @web

Answer (score 0):

You have this code:

```
if (renderer instanceof sigma.renderers.svg) {
    _mouse = renderer.container.firstChild;
}
```

You should check `sigma.renderers.svg` ( `console.log(sigma.renderers.svg)` ) or something else, because as error insists it isn't an object. It could be `undefined`, `null` etc...

Check where you are defining `sigma.renderers.svg`.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the solution was more simple than I thought but at least I learned a lot whilst trying to solve it. The object was correct all the time but I had forgotten to implement necessary renderers. Even though I don't use the SVG type I had to have `../src/renderers/sigma.renderers.svg.js`, included as a script-package.

Thanks for the help!